# GPPSignInButton not loading the Google sign in image

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus

I have used GPPSignInButton in xib and then made a outlet connection . After even trying to set the image using the below code it does not set . Any solution on this would helpful

```
@IBOutlet var signInButton : GPPSignInButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    signInButton?.colorScheme = kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeDark
    signInButton?.style = kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide
    signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn?.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true
    signIn?.clientID = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    signIn?.scopes = ["profile"]
    signIn?.delegate = self
   // signIn?.authenticate()
  //  signIn?.trySilentAuthentication()
}
```

Comment: did you set the button's custom class in your XIB file to "`GPPSignInButton`"?

Comment: I created a UIButton and set it Custom and then derived it from GPPSignInButton in Custom class yet I do not have any luck

Answer (score 2):

> I created a UIButton and set it Custom and then derived it from
>   GPPSignInButton in Custom class yet I do not have any luck

This is the problem.

When creating your xib, you /must/ use a `UIView` from the palette - not a `UIButton`.

If you drag in a `UIButton`, it will not work correctly.

Delete the button you added, drag in a "View", and set it's custom class to `GPPSignInButton`, re-connect your outlet, and you'll be fixed.

---

Do **not** use this one:

[image: Do not use this one]

**Do** use this one:

[image: Do use this one]